# How can I close a program using the back button completely

Tags: android

Consider we have several activities. first we launch the first activity and then using a button we go to the second activity and then using a button we go the other activity and we repeat this action for another activities. Now If I press the back button on the device I will see the previous activities.

How can I close a program using the back button completely?

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //What do I should add here??
    }
```

Comment: you need to onBackPressed on every activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to Quit Application on Button click use this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

and

To kill the complete app and remove it from Running app Task list kill the app through its pid(its nasty)... use this lines before above code.

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: Don't you want to save app data before killing the app?